# Meaning and grammar of 〜かというとだね

Tags: phrases, manga

I'm a bit lost with the bolded sentence from *Doraemon*.

> のび太：　でたらめいうな！！ 人の運命なんか、わかってたまるか！！
>
> ドラえもん：　それがわかるんだ。
>
> ドラえもん：　**どうしてわかるかというとだね。**
>
> ドラえもん：　なに これ？
>
> のび太：　おもち。

I understand どうして、わかる and いう, but I don't get the かと and とだね after them and how it works together.

Comment: Found out the use of たまる as an auxiliary verb after a て form.  No idea about the first sentence.

Comment: Is the sentence broken up like this instead? (どうして)(わかる)(か)(というと)(だね).

Comment: というと has multiple meanings according to Maggie-sensei, [link](http://maggiesensei.com/2010/04/24/request-lesson-というtoiu-ということ（toiukoto-and-many-more/).  I think (2) asking a question and answering yourself would be the most appropriate.

Comment: どうもうありがとうございます。わかりました。：）

Comment: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7128

Comment: Are you sure it is Nobita who says どうしてわかるかというとだね?  That is not a natural flow of conversation.

Comment: No, it's ドラエモン who says it.  The post was edited by somebody else.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I had been thinking about what it's supposed to mean... now it actually makes sense. Btw, only the one who asks questions gets notified about new comments, so it might be better to edit the question instead of adding clarifications as comments.

Comment: BTW, did you know the それが in the second line is a conjunction like "as it is"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> それがわかるんだ。

`I (do know/am able to tell) it [=people's destiny].` First, he claims that he does have the ability indeed.

> `〈どうしてわかるか〉というと`だね。

`As for why I know it, you see..` Now he teases you that he knows why. 〜というと is used to bring up an issue (〜**という**と) and follow it up with the reason (〜という**と**). But here, *Doraemon* doesn't want to reveal the information just yet in this sentence.

> なに これ？

`What's this?` Now he gets distracted before he can explain it.

> おもち。

= お餅. A rice-cake.

---

Grammatically, you can explain it by saying that he mentions the entire phrase instead of using it (`どうしてわかるかというと`)  and appends the copula だ + ね, to bring the listener's attention to it.

Here is an example of how というと is used to offer a reason for a question, namely why some people still get caries even though they use an electric toothbrush that is supposed to be effective against it.

> 電動歯ブラシは効率的に歯についた黴菌【ばいきん】落とすのに有効な道具です。なのに電動歯ブラシを使っている方の中に虫歯や歯周病が治らない方も増えているのです。それは**どうしてかというと**電動の震えているブラシの毛が黴菌【ばいきん】に触れていないのです。
>
> ([source](http://www.nishikata-shika.com/short_musiba.html))

Dictionary-wise, you can find an entry for というと [in the デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154746/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8/). The bolded part applies in this case, although the difference between the 4 senses is rather subtle.

> と‐いうと
>
> １ ある事柄を受けて、そこから予想される内容や導かれる結論を示す。…とすると。…となると。「今週もだめ、来週もだめ―、今月は会えないね」
>
> ２ **ある事柄を提示し、それに関連したことについて下に続ける意を表す。…ということについては。**「新聞記事―、最近公害問題はあまり見かけないね」
>
> ３ ある事柄に関して、代表的なものや、特に結びつきの強いものを挙げる。「コンピューター―彼に聞けばよい」
>
> ４ ある事柄を受けて、それに伴って必ずあとの事柄が生じることを表す。「旅行をする―天気が悪くなる」